# Why does the Django Behave test runner say "ignoring label with dot" when I run a single unit test?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-unittest, python-behave

I have Behave acceptance tests and unittest/django.test unit tests. I have

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_behave.runner.DjangoBehaveTestSuiteRunner'
```

in `settings.py`. I have multiple files of unit tests:

```
myapp/tests
  __init.py__ # empty
  tests_a.py
  tests_b.py
```

I want to run one file of unit tests. (Not one feature; I know how to do that.) When I do

```
python manage.py test myapp.tests.tests_a
```

I get

> Ignoring label with dot in: myapp.tests.tests_a

and then `tests_a.py` runs. Great! Only the tests I wanted to run ran. But what is the test runner talking about ignoring? I haven't found another invocation that runs the tests I want but doesn't emit the warning. What's going on here?

Django 1.10.2, django-behave 0.1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-behave` allows passing app names like this:

```
python manage.py test app1 app2
```

When you do this, it loads the features that belong to each app. You can see that code in [`django_behave/runner.py`](https://github.com/django-behave/django-behave/blob/v0.1.5/django_behave/runner.py). The link I'm giving here points to the latest *released* version at the time of writing this answer. In that module, you'll find:

```
def build_suite(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
    extra_tests = extra_tests or []
    #
    # Add BDD tests to the extra_tests
    #

    # always get all features for given apps (for convenience)
    for label in test_labels:
        if '.' in label:
            print("Ignoring label with dot in: %s" % label)
            continue
        app = get_app(label)

        # Check to see if a separate 'features' module exists,
        # parallel to the models module
        features_dir = get_features(app)
        if features_dir is not None:
            # build a test suite for this directory
            extra_tests.append(self.make_bdd_test_suite(features_dir))

    return super(DjangoBehaveTestSuiteRunner, self
                 ).build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
```

When the code runs into a label that has a dot in it, it assumes it is not an app name and just skips it. So you can do:

```
python manage.py test app1 app2 some.module.name
```

And `some.module.name` won't cause `django-behave` to try to load an app named `some.module.name` and fail.

The very latest version of the code, which is not released yet, no longer puts out a notice about ignoring labels.